# `df` shows that the size of HDD even bigger than it is

Tags: command-line, df

I have VDS which is running under Oracle VirtualBox on my physical server. Ubuntu Server 22.04 is installed on server. The size of Virtual HDD is 500Gb. FastPanel shows that the size of HDD is 491.41Gb, which is understandable. But why `df -H` shows that the size of my HDD is 528G, which is even bigger than real size?

[image]

Comment: the option `-H` "*print sizes in powers of 1000 (e.g., 1.1G)*" ... You want `df -h` ... that is small case `h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man df`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/df.1.html) (*emphasis is mine*):

> **-H, --si**
>
> print sizes in powers of **1000** (e.g., 1.1G)

... so most likely not what you expected as you seem to expect the human readable format which is set by the lowercase `-h` option instead as stated in the manual page:

> **-h, --human-readable**
>
> print sizes in powers of **1024** (e.g., 1023M)

`df` on Ubuntu is provided by the GNU coreutils package and there is more explanation for that in the documentation under [2.2 Block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html) i.e.:

> With human-readable formats, output sizes are followed by a size
> letter such as ‘M’ for megabytes. BLOCK_SIZE=human-readable uses
> powers of 1024; ‘M’ stands for 1,048,576 bytes. BLOCK_SIZE=si is
> similar, but uses powers of 1000 and appends ‘B’; ‘MB’ stands for
> 1,000,000 bytes

.

Comment: Oh, so the difference that the upper case is Gibibytes, the lower case is Gigabytes. I see. Thank you. Sorry for offtopic, but when hard drive manufacturers write, for example, 500G, do they mean gibibytes or gigabytes? Thanks

Comment: @SemyonBayandin It's more like the opposite, I think, please see https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html ... Manufacturers usually use the human readable format when labeling disks AFAIK.